# Combine strong params with other params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I combine strong with other params when creating a new object.

```
def params_test
  params.permit(:test1, :test2, :test3)
end
a = Model.new(params_test)
a.test4 = 'test4'
a.test5 = 'test5'
```

`Test4` and `Test5` they are coming from DB or Cookies or other source in the system. Is there a way to combine all of them into one line? Or two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
Model.new(params_test.merge({ test4: 'test4', test5: 'test5'}))
```